# Getting past the facebook login while using wget

Tags: facebook, cookies, wget

I'm trying to save the webpages of the form `www.example.com?country=austria`

The website `www.example.com` requires login via facebook. If I click on a link `http://www.example.com/social_auth/?p=social_auth_index&action=login&type=facebook` it brings me to the Facebook login page where I type in my username and password and I'm redirected to `www.example.com?country=austria`.

How can I get past this using `wget`? Here are the things I tried:

```
wget --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies cookies.txt -O login.rsp http://www.example.com/social_auth/?p=social_auth_index&action=login&type=facebook
grep authenticity_token login.rsp
```

This generates a cookie file of the following format:

```
www.example.com FALSE   /   FALSE   0   XLBS    XLBS|UdasN|UgzyT
www.example.com FALSE   /   FALSE   0   PHPSESSID   bqkvq1edug387fg314svn7cmgf5
```

What do I need to do afterwards?